# How to change a DIV content using .load and .fadeIn?

Tags: jquery, animation, dynamic

I'm trying to change the content of a Div using:

```
$('#content').click(function() {
    $('#content').fadeOut().load('about.php').fadeIn('normal');
});
```

But it always flashes and I don't know how to solve it, since I'm  a little inexperienced in jQuery.

I looked at this same question in here and I've tried the chosen answers but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the callback functions of the `.fadeOut()` and `.load()` functions. At the moment you are fading-out, adding HTML, and then fading-in all at the same time.

**Try:**

```
//add event handler to click event for the #content element
$('#content').click(function() {

    //cache this element
    var $this = $(this);

    //fadeOut the element
    $this.fadeOut(function () {

        //after fadeOut is done, change it's HTML
        $this.load('about.php', function () {

            //now fadeIn the new HTML, this is in the callback for the `.load()`
            //function because `.load()` is an asynchronous function
            $this.fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

The reason I nested all the `callback` functions is so that each process can complete before the next one is run. First the `.fadeOut()` is allowed to complete, then the `.load()` is allowed to grab the data and place it in the DOM, then we `.fadeIn()` the element with the new HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You might do something like this:

```
$('#content').click(function(){
  $('#content').fadeOut(function(){
     $('#content').load('about.php').fadeIn('normal');
  });
});
```

Using the `load` as a `callback` for the `fadeOut`.